# pandas, selecting float values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, filter

I have a CSV file with two columns (a and b) of data:

```
a    b
30   3000.01
5    3000.02
1    3001.01
5    3001.02
```

I am using pandas to try and select rows that only have the ".01" values in column "b".
So output should be:

```
a    b
30   3000.01
1    3001.01
```

Basically is there a way to search/select rows in column b with the specified criteria of values ending in ".01"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use modulo to strip the decimal then `np.isclose` to generate a boolean array

```
df[np.isclose((df.b % 1).values, .01)]

    a        b
0  30  3000.01
2   1  3001.01
```

Comment: Nice  idea: `df.b % 1` !

Comment: too much sophistication here ! :)

Answer (score 3):

easy peasey

```
df['mystring'] = df.b.astype(str)
df[df.mystring.str.contains(".01")]
```

Comment: Dude. thank you. idk why that small task was so difficult.